# How to route a file to specific gateway?

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, routing, cmd.exe

I have Windows 8.1 Enterprise

I am connected to two internet connections on my PC with this gateways:

> 192.168.1.1 = my isp gateway
>   192.168.43.1 = my mobile usb tethering gateway

Now I want to route my "VPN.exe" file to 192.168.43.1 gateway and then route my "firefox.exe" file to a VPN connection gateway

How can I do this?

Can i use this command?:

```
route add "VPN.exe" mask 255.255.255.255 192.168.43.1 -p
```

---> Please do not recommend: using `ForceBindIP` or `iNetFusion` or `Connectify Dispatch`

I just want to do this with my Windows features like route command or cmd commands

Comment: Simplest way is to use ADs.

Answer (score 0):

> Can i use this command?:

No. The command as written does not make any sense – the "destination" field only takes an IP address. (Besides, the executable isn't even the destination (it is the source); and netmasks only make sense together with a network IP address and not with an executable anyway.)

> I just want to do this with my Windows features like route command or cmd commands

There are no built-in Windows features which would allow this purely based on the executable. Programs *themselves* can bind a socket to a specific local interface, resulting in Windows selecting a gateway that matches that interface best, but there are no known settings that would do this automatically without the program's knowledge.

Your only built-in option is to route *based on destination IP:* for example, you can add a route that uses the 192.168.43.1 gateway to reach your VPN server's IP address.

Comment: how can i extract all of my vpn ip addresses?

Comment: can i route a port to a gateway?